# sp2013: Wildcard before and after search keyword in a list?

Tags: 2013, list, search, sharepoint-server

I am using sp2013. I have created a list. Inside this list I can search. When I search on a keyword it checks only if the results are compare. I would like to show also results where the keyword contais. Like a wildcard (*) before and after the keyword.

Here I try to search inside my list on the keyword `"iphone"`. No results:

[image]

When I search on `"iphone*"` I got 1 result because there is the word `"iphones"` inside the item.

Can I configure this search to do automatic a wildcard before and after the keyword? I know it is possible in a search result webpart in the search query. But this is another situation because I would like to use the search in the list.

Comment: SharePoint does not support wildcards before the word (suffix-matching), it only support prefix-matching (wildcard at the end).

Comment: ok wildcard at the end is also ok, how to?